# DrawToolTipEventArgs graphics property read only and change tooltip location

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have made a graphic component which has its own tooltip style popup.
I use these events:

```
private void ToolTipText_Draw(Object sender, DrawToolTipEventArgs e)

private void ToolTipText_Popup(Object sender, PopupEventArgs e)
```

When the mouse is far left or down, the tooltip its not visible because its out of the visible screen area, so I want to show it in left and/or upper mousepointer position.

In ToolTipText_Draw the parameter DrawToolTipEventArgs e is read only in some properties (like e.Graphics).

I tried:

```
e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(-50, -50);
```

but its "moves" only the tooltip content not the tooltip.

Im really jammed...

*I "paint" the tooltip information and lines, using e.Graphics.DrawString...*

Comment: Try posting the code on how you are showing the ToolTip.  I don't think the drawing information is relevant, and you probably don't need that TranslateTransform call.